# Using arrays in function handler parametr

Tags: matlab, math, octave, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with finding solution to my problem.
Is it possible to use arrays as argument in str2func?
Example:

```
A='@(X)10+(X(1)-2)^2+(X(2)+5)^2';
y=str2func(A);
y(someArray);
```

where X-array 1x2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure:

```
A='@(X) 10+(X(1)-2)^2+(X(2)+5)^2';
y=str2func(A);
y([1 2])
```

just had to use the variable `A` instead of `test` in line 2. BTW, why are you using `str2func`? This is more straightforward:

```
y=@(X) 10+(X(1)-2)^2+(X(2)+5)^2;
y([1 2])
```